# argument error in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have this code

```
   require_relative 'die'

   describe Die do
   describe '#initialize' do
     it 'expects a single argument' do
        expect(Die.instance_method(:initialize).arity).to eq 1
     end

     it 'raises ArgumentError if sides are < 1' do
        expect {              #####line 10
            Die.new(-1)
        }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)

        expect {
            Die.new(0)
        }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
     end
   end
```

I am getting the following error

```
> Die#initialize raises ArgumentError if sides are < 1
   Failure/Error: expect {
     expected ArgumentError but nothing was raised
   # ./spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have marked line 10.Any help how I can remove this error?

and this is my DIE class

```
    class Die
      def initialize(sides)
      end
      def num_of_sides()
      end
     def roll()
     end 
   end
```

Comment: This isn't really an error - you just haven't added the desired behaviour to your Die class

Comment: How do i add the required behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this line inside your `initialize` method:

```
raise ArgumentError if sides < 1
```